# Android: How to add menu items to a ActionBarSherlock MapActivity

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, actionbarsherlock, mapactivity

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock) with [ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps) in my project. I would like to add menu items to the actionbar of my `MapActivity` as it is possible for a standard activity that inherits from `SherlockActivity`. The following code sample shows how to create an icon.

```
public class CustomSherlockActivity extends SherlockActivity {
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        menu.add("Save")
            .setIcon(R.drawable.ic_compose)
            .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
        return true;
    }
```

However, I can **not** use the same method in my `MapActivity` that extends `SherlockMapActivity`. The method `SherlockMapActivity#onCreateOptionsMenu` is defined `final`. Here is the [source code of `SherlockMapActivity`](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock-Plugin-Maps/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/com/actionbarsherlock/app/SherlockMapActivity.java). How then, am I supposed to add actions to the actionbar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the wrong `Menu` class imported. Make sure you are importing the one from the `com.actionbarsherlock.view` package.